# Setting a homepage - doesn't seem to work

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, pages, templates, homepage

have a page (home) that runs a template page-home.php that I can access at mydomin.com/home. I am wanting to have this as my static homepage page, so accessible at mydomain.com/ however I cannot seem to get this to work.

I have change the settings in permalinks to allow for a static homepage, and selected the page I would like to use from the dropdown select box.  On saving and refreshing my site, I just get a blank a white screen. I assumed that as the suffix of the domain is no longer home that wordpress does not know to use the page-home.php

I have changed the name of the file to be the following,

home.php, index.php, homepage.php, page.php and all I get is white screen for my homepage, am I doing something wrong? in 5 years of using wordpress I have never had a problem setting a homepage.

I have also disabled all plugins and set turn the on one by one to make there was nothing in them breaking the page, but no success.

The page is very simple, it is just a loop display posts from a custom post type.

Comment: Try `front-page.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because homepage.php isn't recognized by Wordpress.

The correct file to use is front-page.php.

See: [Template Hierarchy - Front Page Display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display)

Comment: I wanted to complement @Frederik Spang his answer with a link from Chip Bennet about front page dealings in WordPress: http://www.chipbennett.net/2013/09/14/home-page-and-front-page-and-templates-oh-my/

Comment: Also an amazing article I had forgotten all about! Thanks!